# SELECT ActivityHistories For Any SObject

Tags: apex, sobject, dynamic-soql, database, activityhistory

I am writing a code which supposed to process a list of `ActivityHistories` for any SObject which supports them (like Opportunity, Account, etc). And at that point it's impossible to know what is the exact SObject type.

Here is my problem. I can get ActivityHistories for a known SObject type, like this:

```
Opportunity opp = Database.query(
    'SELECT (SELECT Id, Subject, Status, Priority, OwnerId, WhoId '
    + 'FROM ActivityHistories '
    + 'ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC '
    + 'LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0 ) '
    + 'FROM Opportunity '
    + 'WHERE Id = \'0061100000E8pC1\' '
    + 'LIMIT 1');
System.debug(opp.ActivityHistories);
```

But how to get the list of `ActivityHistories` in the case below?

```
Id fid = '0061100000E8pC1';
SObject obj = Database.query(
    'SELECT (SELECT Id, Subject, Status, Priority, OwnerId, WhoId '
    + 'FROM ActivityHistories '
    + 'ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC '
    + 'LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0 ) '
    + 'FROM ' + fid.getSobjectType().getDescribe().label
    + ' WHERE Id = \'' + fid
    + '\' LIMIT 1');
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using the label.... You want the api name instead there, by the way

Comment: Technically, it's simply more efficient to say `String.valueOf(fid.getSObjectType())` instead.

Comment: @sfdcfox you can just use type coercion and drop String.valueOf entirely since you're doing concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`getSObjects`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) method.

```
system.debug(record.getSObjects('ActivityHistories'));
```

You can call it on any SObject instance including opp or obj. Note that a single instance isn't an *object* in proper terminology, but rather a *record*.